# addWithSurcharge exercise alternative answers

Tags: javascript

I had this JavaScript exercise from jshero.net:
**Write a function addWithSurcharge that adds two amounts with surcharge. For each amount less than or equal to 10, the surcharge is 1. For each amount greater than 10 and less than or equal to 20, the surcharge is 2. For each amount greater than 20, the surcharge is 3. The call addWithSurcharge(10, 30) should return 44.**

My solution was :

```
function addWithSurcharge (a,b){
let myS = a+b
if (myS  <10){
return myS  +=2} else if  (myS >10 && myS  <=20){
return myS  +=2} else if (myS >20 && myS <30){
return myS +=3} else if (myS >= 30 && myS <40){
return myS +=4} else if(myS >40){
return myS +=5}
}
```

Somehow it worked, I passed the challenge but I feel like there was an easier way to solve this. Do you know other alternative answers for this exercise?

Comment: This is very close to asking for improvements to working code, which is off-topic for Stack Overflow and on-topic at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could write it as a `switch` statement. something like this:

```
function addWithSurcharge (a,b) {
  let myS = a+b
  switch (true){
    case myS < 10:
      return myS + 2
    case (myS > 10 && myS <= 20):
      return myS + 2
    case (myS > 20 && myS < 30):
      return myS + 3
    case (myS >= 30 && myS < 40):
      return myS + 4
    default:
      return myS + 5
  }
}
```

Comment: I did it now and I got the following error message :

**Invalid left-hand side in assignment. Error reading your code!

Test-Error! Correct the error and re-run the tests!**

I forgot to mention the fact that this is for an else if challenge. But it does not say that it's mandatory to use else if statements.

Comment: Still not working.
Now the error is **addWithSurcharge(1, 1) does not return 4, but false.

Test-Error! Correct the error and re-run the tests!**.

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: @DefNotBruceWayne try now, sorry. there were some brackets the wrong way around

Comment: I'm sorry, the same error keeps appearing. **addWithSurcharge(1, 1) does not return 4, but 7.

Test-Error! Correct the error and re-run the tests!**.

Comment: Here is the link to the challenge https://www.jshero.net/en/koans/elseif.html .

Comment: I've made one more change. try that now. when I tested it, Im getting 4 now

Comment: all tests passed now for me

Comment: IT'S WORKING. Thank you very much. All the results came back as expected. This is really nice.

Comment: @DefNotBruceWayne no worries. upvote the answer AND mark as correct if it helped you, thanks :)

Comment: Have a look on my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you can round to the superior decade and then divide by 10.
I'm surprised you passed the test cause you don't really fit the problem, you forgot every case when equal to 10, 20, 30, ...

By the way, this is my way to answer your problem. With this way it's "infinite" but if you wan't stop adding after 40, just add `Math.max(X, (decadeRounded / 10))` where `X` is your maximum, for example `Math.max(5, (decadeRounded / 10))`

```js
function addWithSurcharge (a,b) {
  let myS = a + b
  let decadeRounded = Math.round( (myS/10) ) * 10;

  return myS + (decadeRounded / 10);
}

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = addWithSurcharge(10, 20);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
function addWithSurcharge(a, b) {
  if (a <= 10) {
    a += 1
  } else if (a > 10 && a <= 20) {
    a += 2
  } else if (a > 20) {
    a += 3
  }

  if (b <= 10) {
    b += 1
  } else if (b > 10 && b <= 20) {
    b += 2
  } else if (b > 20) {
    b += 3
  }

  return a + b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function addWithSurcharge(a, b) {
    i = 0;
    if (a <= 10) {
      i = i + 1;
    } else if (a > 10 && a <= 20) {
      i = i + 2;
    } else if (a > 20) {
      i = i + 3;
    }

    if (b <= 10) {
      i = i + 1;
    } else if (b > 10 && b <= 20) {
      i = i + 2;
    } else if (b > 20) {
      i = i + 3;
    }

    return a + b + i;
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).